# How make this Android NodeMCU TCP socket code auto-reconnect?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, nodemcu

Use case: 
NodeMCU connects to Android over TCP socket, then Android plays a sound, when user presses a button, which is connected to NodeMCU.

I couldn't find a way (that I could believe as reliable) to have Android's ServerSocket to notice a reset from NodeMCU client socket, right at once, when NodeMCU's socket is disconnected, or trying to reconnect.

This is my newbee socket code bellow, which I got it working also with the help of this forum. I tried to make it as short as possible when posting here, keeping only relevant parts, but if you need I can just drop all the code, so please let me know in case.

Please suggest me a way. Any other comment to help me understand more of sockets is very welcome.

I'd like to finally learn what sockets are!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ServerSocket serverSocket;
Thread socketServerThread = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    Globals.snd = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bike_horn);// Globals - static class
    //...
    socketServerThread = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
    socketServerThread.start();
}
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (serverSocket != null) {...//try close it}
}
private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {
    //...
    static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        BufferedReader input = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket();
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            serverSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(SocketServerPORT));
            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                while(socket.isConnected()){
                    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    message = input.readLine();
                    if(message == null) break;
                    int x = Integer.valueOf(message);
                    if(x == 1) Globals.snd.start();
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException e) {// print error stack
        }finally{//close socket, dataInputStream, dataOutputStream
        }
```

NodeMCU code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
//...variables defined
void setup() {
    //...connect to wifi
    client.connect(host, port);
}
void loop() {
    if(!client.connected()){
        if (!client.connect(host, port)) {
            return;
        }
    }

    while(digitalRead(beepBtnPin) == LOW && client.connected()){
        client.println("2");
        client.flush();
        delay(500);
    }
}
```

Comment: `input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));`. You should do that only once for a client. Take it out of the loop and put it just before.

Comment: `message = input.readLine();`. Do not use a global variable. Change to `String message = input.readLine();`.

Comment: `DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;    BufferedReader input = null;`. Take that out and put in your ClientThread.

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions in last days on my various posts helped to forward my learning project. If I'm getting it right, the reason "do input=new... only once" is to not to create memory leaks, and I guess that "no global" is because it is supposed to be a multithread environment and it is to prevent side effects. Could you please let me know if I understood you right and also the reason behind the last comment "put in your ClientThread" please?

Comment: Please put the code after accept in ClientThread. Its no work. In ten minutes we can get this right. You dont need a book.

Comment: `the reason "do input=new... only once" is to not to create memory leaks`. No. That is not the reason.

Comment: Thank you, I applied your suggestions and now I have no question / problem with having the socket to reconnect in case of loss. The new problem I have is with the android (that seems) putting the app to sleep, even though I implemented a sticky service. I posted the code with ClientThread here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50672633/2275800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all code after

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

In a so called client thread. This is normally done to handle more clients at once.

The server then immediately waits for the next client to connect.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it, could you please provide a link, where I could read a code of "client thread" possibly? (I suppose that you mean that in that case, the new request will get the socket reopen, but I had some binding errors with "port in use", so I could believe that Android code did not sense the socket is reset from client side.)

Comment: I have no link. Just define a class ClientThread which extends Thread. The constructor should take that socket parameter. Put all code in the run() of your class. It is not much work. Post your class and adapted code here.

Comment: Thank you, I picked up a small book on Java Networking (only 190 pages), I'd go through it, then post new code here.